# Missing files when moving the bitmonero folder

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, blockchain

I decided to move the bitmonero folder to a 256GB penstick as my hard drive was nearly full. However when I copied the folder to the new location I noticed that 2 files seem to have disappeared, namely lock.mdb (in the lmdb folder) and p2pstate.bin. This occurred on both the original and the one on the penstick.

I am using the GUI Monero Version 0.17.2.0 and a Trezor Model T, running on Linux Mint 19.3. The wallet is still synchronizing, but slowly.

Do these missing files affect the installation or will I have to download from scratch and start again.I have searched and can find no answer.

Answer (score 1):

> ... namely lock.mdb (in the lmdb folder) and p2pstate.bin

Neither of these files are required for backing up / moving.

> Do these missing files affect the installation or will I have to download from scratch and start again.

No, you will not need to download the blockchain again.